# How do I manage "Want to go" and "Favorite" places in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

In the Google Maps mobile app, "Your Places", consists of three categories of places:

- Favorites
- Want to go
- Starred places

as well as others that can be added by the user.

<del>In Google Maps in browsers however, there are no such groupings and only "Starred places" appear.</del>

This same factoring is now available in the browser version of Google Maps, but there remains no way there to move items from one grouping to another.

How do I mange the various lists of saved places in Google Maps, especially in the browser version of Maps?

Is there a way to move a place from one list to another; or to change the list a given place is in?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find this explicitly in the Google Help, but it seems that only the "Starred places" list is editable from the browser.

- The ["Save favorite places" help page](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3184808) describes how to star a location, and it has tabs for Computer, Android, and iPhone/iPad.
- The ["Create a list of places" help page](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7280933) describes how to add places to the other lists. Unlike the starring page, this page ONLY talks about the "app", and does NOT have a tab for "Computer".

You can "Share" the other  lists from your phone, which would allow you to view (but not not edit) them from a computer. Be careful though - the sharing uses public URLs, so don't do it with any lists you want to keep private.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, January 12th, 2018, in the web app, there is no way to move places between  lists in batches, but:

- You can access and customize your lists by url https://www.google.com/maps/@0,0z/data=!4m2!10m1!1e1?hl=en:

  [image]

  [image]
- You can work your way through each item and move them between lists e.g. "Favorites" and "Want to go":

  [image]

Comment: I don't see anything new since the question was updated. Is there now "a way to move a place from one list to another; or to change the list a given place is in"?

Comment: Yes there is, as the screenshot shows. The new feature is probably getting a progressive rollout (geographical or A/B test) so it may take a while before you see it.

Comment: That's item by item, not *an edit of the list* (is it?). What you're describing is just the surfacing of other lists on individual items (in the desktop as on mobile). The question is about editing the list itself.

Comment: Indeed the only way to change the list an item is in, is by finding it individually. I misunderstood your question then.

Comment: Updated accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't found a way of doing it batchwise. However, if you open your starred places list and click on a place it will open; if you then click on the *Saved* icon you can save it in another of your lists or create a new one to save it in, then return to your list using the Back to List link. This means that you can structure your starred list by working through it and saving the places in your custom & appropriate lists. When you are finished You can use the Edit List link to delete the places you have processed from the (old, chaotic) Starred places list.

Comment: That’s just editing individual places and has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: The last sentence of the question is "Is there a way to move a place from one list to another; or to change the list a given place is in?" Nothing to do with the question?

Comment: upvoting because, as @Kayway says, it IS a way to move an item from one list to another.  And in fact it's the way that I just now stumbled upon on my phone.  Just because crome doesn't like that way doesn't mean it's not a valid, accurate answer.